# Cannot correctly include PDFClown in my project

Tags: java, pdfclown

I'm trying to use PDFClown for the first time.
As written in the ReadMe file, i tried to import PDFClown Project through the following steps
in my Java Workspace, Eclipse IDE
1) File => import... => Existing Project into Workspace => then i selected the Java folder of the downloaded [PDFClown Zip](http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/downloads.html) (version 0.1.2 Beta)

After this i have 5 projects in my package explorer, 4 owned by PDFClown plus mine project.
Now, i get 38 errors; the last one is relative to an implementation of a HelloWorld in my original project.

EDIT: i'm sorry for the messy error reporting, i'll be glad if someone can help showing it in a more friendly manner

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The import org.pdfclown cannot be resolved  PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 7  Java Problem
The import org.pdfclown cannot be resolved  PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 8  Java Problem
Sample cannot be resolved to a type PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 16 Java Problem
The method run() of type PDFGenerator must override or implement a supertype method PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 19 Java Problem
File cannot be resolved to a type   PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 24 Java Problem
File cannot be resolved to a type   PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 24 Java Problem
The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 10 Java Problem
Document cannot be resolved to a type   PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 28 Java Problem
The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 11 Java Problem
Document cannot be resolved to a type   PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 41 Java Problem
The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 12 Java Problem
Page cannot be resolved to a type   PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 45 Java Problem
The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 13 Java Problem
Page cannot be resolved to a type   PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 45 Java Problem
The import org.apache cannot be resolved    HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 15 Java Problem
PrimitiveComposer cannot be resolved to a type  PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 49 Java Problem
The import org.apache cannot be resolved    HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 16 Java Problem
PrimitiveComposer cannot be resolved to a type  PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 49 Java Problem
The import org.apache cannot be resolved    HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 17 Java Problem
StandardType1Font cannot be resolved to a type  PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 54 Java Problem
The import org.apache cannot be resolved    HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 18 Java Problem
StandardType1Font cannot be resolved to a variable  PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 56 Java Problem
HttpServlet cannot be resolved to a type    HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 38 Java Problem
HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved to a type HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 42 Java Problem
FileItem cannot be resolved to a type   HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 137    Java Problem
ServletFileUpload cannot be resolved to a type  HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 56 Java Problem
FileItem cannot be resolved to a type   HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 61 Java Problem
The import org.pdfclown cannot be resolved  PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 6  Java Problem
DiskFileItemFactory cannot be resolved to a type    HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 55 Java Problem
The import org.pdfclown cannot be resolved  PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 5  Java Problem
ServletFileUpload cannot be resolved to a type  HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 56 Java Problem
The import org.pdfclown cannot be resolved  PDFGenerator.java   /sitodove/src   line 4  Java Problem
FileItem cannot be resolved to a type   HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 52 Java Problem
FileItemFactory cannot be resolved to a type    HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 55 Java Problem
ServletFileUpload cannot be resolved    HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 46 Java Problem
FileItem cannot be resolved to a type   HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 50 Java Problem
HttpServletResponse cannot be resolved to a type    HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 43 Java Problem
ServletException cannot be resolved to a type   HelloWorld.java /pdfclown.samples.web/src/org/pdfclown/samples/web  line 44 Java Problem
```

EDIT: Actually i have downloaded the org.apache.commons.fileupload Jar, then included it by going on Project => Properties => Java Build Path => Libraries => Add External Jars
Now i have less error but... does it really have to be that complicated?

Comment: have you included the pdfclown project into your main project? this does NOT mean simply exporting the PDFClown project to your workspace

Comment: Can you please tell me what 'include' precisely means? I'm getting crazy, don't want to miss any single word. How do i include a project? I'm used to import jars.. isn't there any way to do this with pdfclown? Please have a look to the EDIT

Comment: I downloaded the zip just now and exported to my workspace. It builds just fine(just built the gui sample that came with the zip)

Comment: Which files are causing the above errors ? to test the web example, you will need servlet-api.jar. The other 2 projects (cli and gui) are working fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to include PDF Clown in your project, you DO NOT need to import its distribution projects (which contain both the full sources AND the precompiled jars): what you have to do is just to *pick the **precompiled jars** you can find within the distribution (PDFClown/java/pdfclown.lib/build/package)* and place them in your project's dependencies.

Alternatively, if you want to get a try to the **distribution samples** (CLI-based, GUI-based and Web-based), then you have to follow the README, considering that (as your error report reveals) *if you want to use the web samples* (because you already know how web projects work, right?) *you have to set up your web server* (BTW, commons-fileupload-1.2.jar is already included in the project, no need for hunting). If you are unaware of web server setup in eclipse, then please look at the trillion tutorials available on the web, otherwise you can simply close the web sample project (pdfclown.samples.web) in eclipse so it doesn't annoy you anymore and you can happily run the CLI and GUI samples!